# Извлечение строки между двух тегов

Tags: php

Друзья, добрый вечер.

Есть строка:

```
$text = "
Текст Текст Текст
[photo]Photo.jpg[photo]
Текст Текст Текст
[photo]Photo2.jpg[photo]
";
```

необходимо найти, то что находится между тегов [photo].

Пробовал

```
explode('[photo]', $text);
```

Но это не совсем подходим. Так как
`explode('[photo]', $text)[0];` выведет => "Текст Текст Текст ", а мне нужно что бы выводились только названия фоток.

Кто нибудь может помочь с решением данной проблемы ?

Comment: А закрывающих тегов нету?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$regex = "#\[(.*)\](.*?)\[(.*)\]#";
$code = preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[2]);

$regex = "#\[photo\](.*?)\[photo\]#";
$code = preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Обычно bb-теги парные *(есть открывающий и закрывающий тег)*. Но если у вас нет закрывающего, то нужно после каждого открывающего тега проверять строку на наличие расширения:

```
$text = 'Текст Текст Текст
[photo]Photo.jpg[photo]
Текст Текст Текст
[photo]Photo2.jpg[photo]';

$arr = [];
! preg_match_all('~\[photo]\K\S+\.\pL{3,4}~', $text, $arr) ?: $arr = $arr[0];

print_r($arr);
```

---

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Photo.jpg
    [1] => Photo2.jpg
)
```